# Where do I find Outlook Calendar permissions in Outlook 2019?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2019

In the previous Outlook versions, I could set permissions like this:

[image]

But where can I find this "Outlook calendar permission" dialog in Outlook 2019?

Now I can only find a dialog like this:

[image]

According to this Microsoft [support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-an-outlook-calendar-with-other-people-353ed2c1-3ec5-449d-8c73-6931a0adab88) I should be able to find a "Calendar permission" button on the "Home" tab - but this is missing in 2019.

Comment: What type of mail account are you using in Outlook?

Comment: We're using Office 365.

Comment: It seems that the dialogue box of Calendar Permission has been changed to the first image recently.